# With Hibernate, is there a way to avoid using a String for column names in my HQL/SQL/Criteria conditions?

Tags: java, hibernate

In the Criteria condition below:

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
// To get records having salary more than 2000
cr.add(Restrictions.gt("salary", 2000));
```

First of all, is "salary" a property of my Employee entity or a column of the database table?

Second of all, if I ever want to change/remove this "salary", will I have to search all my queries to update them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is hibernate's [metamodel](http://hibernate.org/orm/tooling/) generator. This is a build-time tool that generates a new class from each of your entities, with appropriate annotations to allow you to use the generated class' fields instead of strings in criteria queries.

For your example, you would be able to write

```
cr.add(Restrictions.gt(Employee_.salary, 2000));
```

The only gotcha when refactoring is that the IDE refactoring tools do not seem to be smart about refactoring uses of the generated metamodel classes when you refactor your entity. The workaround for this is to refactor the entity and do the same refactor on the generated class. While the refactor in the generated class is not directly necessary (it will get re-generated with the changes), it has the effect of refactoring all uses of the metamodel class that must change.

If you were to remove `salary` from your `Employee` entity, it would automatically be removed from the generated `Employee_` metamodel class. This would give you compilation errors for all queries that mention `salary`. This is much better than the alternative, where everything continues to compile but fails when you execute the query.

Comment: An alternative which would also give strongly typed queries would be querydsl http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch02s02.html

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, is "salary" a property of my Employee entity or a column of the database table?

Yes, salary is a property of Employee entity and not database table column name.

> Second of all, if I ever want to change/remove this "salary", will I have to search all my queries to update them?

If you remove salary field from employee, you will have to remove from queries as well.

Comment: That sucks! Imagine a large system with 1000s of queries. Every time you refactor your entity, to  change/remove a property, you have to do a search/replace all over the place?

Comment: Another question, when you refactor an entity, you are changing ORM structure as well as database structure. So when it is changing definitely you need to change queries too right? What can a `SELECT e.name FROM Employee e` do if the name field itself is not there?

Comment: Not necessarily. One thing is the property name, for example `getLogin()` another thing is the column name it is mapped to, for example `username`. What's the purpose of ORM mapping, if a change requires an update everywhere?

Comment: I was talking in a situation when field is removed. Column name need not be changed. You can use NamedQuery and assign a query to it. and use the query name to execute it. This way even if there is change, then the change would be done only in NamedQuery and not every string.

Comment: Can you provide an example in your answer of the workaround you are suggesting?

Comment: This link could help. http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named. I still wonder why you are using criteria if you can simply write the query in jpql.

Comment: If JQPL mitigates this problem, I would be interested in an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110449/discussion-between-prasad-kharkar-and-pika-sucar).